# How fast is mprotect

Tags: c, linux, mmap, mmu

My question is how fast is `mprotect`. What will be the difference between mprotecting say 1 MB of contiguous memory as compared to 1 GB of contiguous memory? Of course I can measure the time, but I want to know what goes under the hood.

Comment: Reference: [mm/mprotect.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mprotect.c#L232) and [LDD3 ch. 15](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf).

Comment: "Of course I can calculate the time" -- assuming you _meant_ "Of course I can **measure** the time"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick check on the source seems to indicate that it iterates over the process mappings in the selected region and change their flags. If you protect less than a whole mapping it'll split it into two or three.

So in short it's `O(n)` where `n` is the number of times you've called mmap.

You can see all the current maps in `/proc/pid/maps`

Comment: Does mprotect iterates over pages? E.g. is mprotect of 100 MB of same speed as 1000 MB? (in case of single mmap of equal size).

Comment: I have to wonder if the effects of manipulating page tables (i.e. potentially slower memory access for some time after the call completes) would have more of an impact than the fact that you've looped over N mappings.

Comment: Not only modifying a bit for each page, but also invalidating TLB of current CPU core and of other CPU cores.

Answer (score 2):

It is O(n) on page count in the region too, because it should change a access bits on all PTEs (Page translation Entries, which describes virtual->physical page mappings in PageTable). Calltree:

```
mprotect
-> 
mprotect_fixup
->
change_pte_range
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mprotect.c#L32

```
 47     do {
 48                 oldpte = *pte;
 49                 if (pte_present(oldpte)) {
 50                         pte_t ptent;
 51 
 52                         ptent = ptep_modify_prot_start(mm, addr, pte);
 53                         ptent = pte_modify(ptent, newprot);
 54 
 55                         /*
 56                          * Avoid taking write faults for pages we know to be
 57                          * dirty.
 58                          */
 59                         if (dirty_accountable && pte_dirty(ptent))
 60                                 ptent = pte_mkwrite(ptent);
 61 
 62                         ptep_modify_prot_commit(mm, addr, pte, ptent);
 63                 } else if (PAGE_MIGRATION && !pte_file(oldpte)) {
 64                         swp_entry_t entry = pte_to_swp_entry(oldpte);
 65 
 66                         if (is_write_migration_entry(entry)) {
 67                                 /*
 68                                  * A protection check is difficult so
 69                                  * just be safe and disable write
 70                                  */
 71                                 make_migration_entry_read(&entry);
 72                                 set_pte_at(mm, addr, pte,
 73                                         swp_entry_to_pte(entry));
 74                         }
 75                 }
 76         } while (pte++, addr += PAGE_SIZE, addr != end);
```

Note the increment: `addr += PAGE_SIZE, addr != end);`